# VPS CPU steal time

Tags: vps

I ordered a VPS at Contabo today, these are the specs (screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwA21.jpg)

- Quad Core either Intel® Xeon® E5-2620v3, E5-2630v4 or 4114
- 12 GB RAM (guaranteed)
- 300 GB Storage (100% SSD)
- 100 Mbit/s-Port

I've now set it up, and it is running an IRI node on it.

I feel a bit strange because of the CPU steal time

[image]

Green is idle, orange used, the white band at the top is the steal time.

You see two peaks. The first one is when I stopped IRI, then I let it turned off for a minute, and started it again.

This is what /proc/cpuinfo looks like

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 2199.998
cache size      : 16384 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat
bugs            :
bogomips        : 4399.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

What does this say about the server? IRI is running inside Docker, it has the latest Kernel (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64) on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

I have another node running in VirtualBox with Ubuntu as the guest and Windows 10 as the host with a low power Xeon CPU. No matter how much work you throw at the CPU's, there's never a steal time to be seen (only one VM running)

Is this something to worry about, or even a slight ripoff? Or is this normal?

Comment: Is this about the *subject* of Iota or more of a hardware issue only related to Iota coincidentally?

Comment: About suitable vps-providers for a node. Maybe serverfault would be a more appropiate place.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Can you move it over there?

Comment: @RobertCartaino: You have migrated this to [meta.sf], so I had to reject this. That said, I've no idea what OPs question actually is and I somehow doubt this would qualify as a question regarding system administration in a professional/business context anyway.